# Which GIS software or plugins can perform a Cellular Automata Simulation?

Tags: cellular-automata

I am interested in running cellular Automata to run a simulation on city growth. Which GIS software can run this out of the box, or via plugins?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to do this in ArcGIS using Repast's [Agent Analyst Extension](http://www.institute.redlands.edu/agentanalyst/) a couple of years ago. It allows you to do agent-based geosimulation, CA included. It uses Java or a subset of Python called Repast Python. Not sure if it's still supported, though. It goes by [Repast Simphony](http://repast.sourceforge.net/) now. Here is a [walkthrough on creating cellular automata models](http://code.google.com/p/cscs-repast-demos/wiki/CA_Walkthrough) to get you started.

Another tool for ArcGIS is the [cellular automata tool that comes with Hawth's Analysis tools](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/cellauto1d.php). I don't have any experience with that one though.

Comment: I was about to post about Agent Analyst. I have not had any luck with it in 10.1 SP1 though. The Agent Analyst environment does not appear after creating an Agent Analyst tool. Should work in 10.0 though.

Comment: Only used it for 10.0 and 9.3. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: BTW, Agent Analyst for ArcGIS 10.0 is here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/agent-analyst/

Comment: Excellent!!! This looks promising.

Comment: Actually I got it to work in 10.1 by correcting the values of the environment variables added by the installer to point to the java, javaw and arcobjects.jar files under the ArcGIS 10.1 install directory.

Answer (score 4):

IDRISI works quiet well. And it seems someone ask quite the same question [here](https://forums.clarklabs.org/entries/21816678-cellular-automata-using-idrisi).

On open source side, there is [TerraME](http://www.terrame.org/doku.php).

Answer (score 4):

You may have a look at [the GAMA platform](http://gama-platform.org/):

> GAMA is a simulation platform, which aims at providing field experts, modelers, and computer scientists with a complete modeling and simulation development environment for building spatially explicit agent-based simulations (...). GAMA provides the modeler with the ability to use arbitrarily complex GIS data as environments for the agents.

For CA, see for example [this tutorial](http://gama-platform.org/tutorials#PredatorPrey).

Answer (score 2):

The best integration of a GIS with a cellular automata modeling system is [TerraME](http://www.terrame.org/doku.php) from INPE in Brazil.

Another CA modeling system with som GIS-like capabilities is [NetLogo](http://www.ccl.sesp.northwestern.edu/netlogo/). The logo language takes some getting used to, but this is a great CA platform.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any COTS product will have a built-in tool for CA.
You can write your own logic or use a combination of built-in tools to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend GeoSOS for ArcGIS. It is a software add-in(plugin) runs in ArcGIS Desktop, can be easily installed in ArcMap from the software version 10.1 or above. GeoSOS for ArcGIS is a free and open source software, can be downloaded at GeoSOS website (http://www.geosimulation.cn). It has been downloaded more than 4000 times in the last 3 years by the users in 46 countries all round the world.

GeoSOS for ArcGIS uses the GeoSOS theory (Geographical Simulation and Optimization Systems) to provides the full functions to simulate, predict, optimize and display the geographical pattern and dynamical process, such as land use change, urban growth, natural protection areas zoning and facilities sitting, etc. It has a user-friendly and wizard-style interface, so it's easy to run a CA simulation/prediction process, or a ACO(Ant Colony Optimization)-based spatial optimization problem.

As maybe the only software integrated spatial simulation and optimization capability currently, GeoSOS for ArcGIS comprises geographic simulator and optimizer, which use multiple CA models and ACO-based model respectively, or coupling the two results to solve the complex spatial simulation and optimization problems.

please see the papers below to get more information about GeoSOS theory and the software GeoSOS for ArcGIS:

Li X, Lao C H, Liu X P, Chen Y M. , 2011. Coupling urban cellular automata with ant colony optimization for zoning protected natural areas under a changing landscape. International Journal of Geographical Information Science. 25(4), 575–593. 
http://www.geosimulation.cn/Papers/IJGIS2011%20Concepts,%20methodologies,%20and%20tools%20of%20an%20integrated%20geographical.pdf

Liu X P, Lao C H, Li X, 2012. An integrated approach of remote sensing, GIS and swarm intelligence for zoning protected ecological areas. Landscape Ecology, 27: 447-463.
http://www.geosimulation.cn/Papers/2012%20Landscape%20Ecol-swarm%20intelligence%20for%20zoning%20protected%20ecological%20areas.pdf