# Agent Analyst tool interface will not open on ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, installation, agent-analyst

For me the Agent Analyst tool interface won't open.

I have ArcGIS 10.1 sp1 installed on my computer.

I have followed these steps so far:

1. added the refresh.config.exe text file ([ArcGIS 10.1 using Repast's Agent Analyst Extension - refresh.exe does not work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48655/arcgis-10-1-using-repasts-agent-analyst-extension-refresh-exe-does-not-work))
2. changed values 10.0 to 10.1 in files agent_analyst.bat and agent_analyst_run.bat in agent analyst installation folder
   3- added the ArcGIS 10.1 installation path "for example C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1" to environment variables ARC_JAVA & ARC_JAVAW & ARCOBJECTS_JAR ([Which GIS software or plugins can perform a Cellular Automata Simulation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44285/which-gis-software-or-plugins-can-perform-a-cellular-automata-simulation/44291#44291))

I restarted and still have had no luck (just a black box flashes up when I create a new agent analyst tool or try to edit the tool).

Is there some other step I need to do or have I done one of the above steps incorrectly?

Comment: Is the file named `refresh.config.exe` as noted above, or `Refresh.exe.config` as named in blah238's answer? It should be the second one, and should be located in the same directory as refresh.exe

Comment: The file is named Refresh.exe.config and I have saved it in the 'Refresh' folder (C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst\Refresh - is that the correct place?) which is where the Refresh.exe file is located.

Comment: Please help me to do numbers 2 and 3 in this instruction. I can find the files agent_analyst.bat and agent_analyst_run.bat in C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst, but don't know how to change values. Also, I couldn't find out how to do number 3. Please explain in more detail. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to install Agent Analyst to my ArcGIS 10.1. I think I am almost there but the analyst does not open within ArcGIS. I have followed all the threads above and now I am able to open Agent Analyst separately outside ArcGIS and initiate it. In ArcGIS, I can't find the Cougar Model Toolbox, but when I right click any other toolbox, I do see the Agent Analyst inactive. Any suggestions? Please Advice. J M In ArcGIS](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FB2q0.jpg)

Comment: I am using 10.5 and cant get this software to work. Can someone please clarify how to change the Environment Variables. Where do I locate these?

Answer (score 3):

I also got Agent Analyst to work with ArcGIS 10.2 (at least so far).  I had to perform the steps noted above, but given that it was a bit confusing with some of the responses I will summarize here:

1. Create **Refresh.exe.config** file with a text editor and save it along with **Refresh.exe** (typically in **C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst\Refresh**).  The **Refresh.exe.config** contents will be identical to the contents of the configuration file described here ("Update 2"): [ArcGIS 10.1 using Repast's Agent Analyst Extension - refresh.exe does not work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48655/arcgis-10-1-using-repasts-agent-analyst-extension-refresh-exe-does-not-work) but you must replace newVersion="10.1.0.0" with newVersion="10.2.0.0".
2. As noted above, edit the **agent_analyst.bat** and **agent_analyst_run.bat** files in the installation folder (**C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst**) so that the folder paths contain Desktop10.2 in the folder path strings:

   ```
   rem set ARC_JAVA="C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\java\jre\bin\java"
   rem set ARC_JAVAW="C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\java\jre\bin\javaw"
   rem set ARCOBJECTS_JAR="C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\java\lib\arcobjects.jar"
   ```
3. Then, edit your Environment Variables to make sure that ARC_JAVA, ARC_JAVAW, and ARCOBJECTS_JAR have a fully specified path entered for each variable (like what is in the .bat files above).
4. Then, in my Environment Variables, I had to move ARC_JAVA (**C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\java\jre\bin\java**), ARC_JAVAW (**C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\java\jre\bin\javaw**), ARCOBJECTS_JAR (**C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\java\lib\arcobjects.jar**), AGENT_ANALYST (**C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst**), and AGENT_ANALYST_VOL (**C:**) from my User Variables to my System Variables.  Depending on your situation, I foresee that some people may not need to do this.  If you install software and manage your system with a separate ADMIN account, then I think you will need to do this...I had to do so to get it to work.
5. Finally, make sure you restart your system and open a fresh ArcGIS session...

I'm new to Agent Analyst so I don't know if there will be other issues down the road, but now I am at least able to see the Agent Analyst user interface when adding a new tool so it appears that everything is working well so far.

Comment: These steps worked for me for 10.3.1 as of 8/23/2017. In my Refresh.exe.config file I used `newVersion="10.3.0.0"`, and of course changed the environment variables to `Desktop10.3`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Instead of a general C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1 path in environment variables. Give the whole direct path to the file... remember not the folder but the file. restart and it works.