# The updateDisplay action in Agent Analyst does not update my ArcMap display

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, agent-analyst

I use ArcGIS 10.4. and Win 8.0. .I have a problem with Agent Analyst in a model-level action. I did all steps of the Exercise 2f in the book.The model start running, the Repast output suddenly stopped working, and an error shows " refresh has stopped working", "check online for the solution...".The updateDisplay action in Agent Analyst does not update my ArcMap display. When I deleted the agent's updateDisplay, I didn't receive any Error.The attached file is the print screen of the Error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a virtual C: Drive with Windows 7 on my Windows 8 and installed ArcGIS 10.2 on virtual Drive. then I went through the structures mentioned in this
[Agent Analyst tool interface will not open on ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/57563/91236)
then the problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have follow the steps mention in [Agent Analyst tool interface will not open on ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57563/agent-analyst-tool-interface-will-not-open-on-arcgis-for-desktop) and then also you are getting same problem. This is due to Refresh.exe.config file. Your system will be taking as a text file. Download this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N6S72Nky_Ayf6aoFxThR3A-F9qB9n5So/view?usp=sharing) and paste it in **C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst\Refresh** location. Open this file with notepad and change the arcgis version accordingly.

It is working on my system now.